# Are Black Holes just explosions in slow motion?

Tags: black-holes

I recently asked a question here relating to what it means if we saw "Physics break down". Thus i had a strong look into Black Holes. Or at least some Articles about them. And i couldnt help but ask, could the concept of a Singularity be bs ?

**The Idea**

Ok so from what i understand, if you fell into a Black Hole, a few things happen. Firstly you never enter the Even Horizon, it is always infront of you. Secound, the Universe will beginn to speed up. To the point where you can see entire Galaxys move.

Thus, after a while everything just Merges into a Glowing somthing. So you would have the Black Event Horizon right below and a Bright Universe above you. At least for a while. It would get darker over time as the Star´s start to burn out. Near the end of you, everything just turns Black.

Then you start to notice that the Event Horizion gets smaller. And suddenly a bright flash and thats it. You are dead and so is everything else.
What just happened was that the Black Hole went all big boom.

**What ?**

Let´s Imagine two external Observers and a Star about to go Supernova. For the first Observer, lets say Peter, Time passes at the same speed as on Earth. And that can never change. Or secound Observer, Theia, however has something special about her. Her passage of Time is "Locked" to the Center of the Star. And that too can never change.

So let´s start.
The Star goes Supernova and creates a Black Hole.

For Peter, the Supernova is pretty but besides that, there really is not a lot to look at. Excluding the Gamma Ray Bursts of course. The Black Hole just sort of Sits where it is and dosnt appear to change. At all.
After a very long time, the Black Hole does indeed change. It loses Mass and then, after a metric fu*kton time, it Explodes. Trillions of Years have passed, the Universe is very dark and overall, Peter wants his money back.

But what about Theia ?

For her, everything was a bit faster. From her POV, the Instance the Core of the Star collapsed into a Black Hole, the Universe around her Speed up in an Exponatial Fashion. Whole Galaxys moved and in Micorsecounds, she could "see" how all the Stars went out. Almost all at once. The Center is bright as hell. The Sphere in the Center, after Collpsing for a while starts to expand again. Just as fast as everything speed up, it slows down again.  She finds herself in a Field of Radiation with Zero Stars in the Sky.

For her, almost no time has passed. It was just like a really crazy Explosion.

**Singularity == BS ?**

The Matter of the Black Hole never actually compressed into a point with Volume = 0. And it was also never Black, at least for Theia. Thus, no Singularity. The Core if you want might be comparable to a Neutron Star. Only here Matter, or Energy i suppose, collapses into the smallest Possible Volume. Which is not Zero but still *very* small.

**Why is the Core bright for Theia but Black for Peter ?**

The idea here is also time. Lets say you have a Lightbulb which Emits exactly one Photon every secound. For you, it is not Glowing. But if you for example saw time at 1000000x speed, it would very much Glow.

Same story here, since Theia´s Time is locked to the Time of the Core, time effectivly runs Trillions of times faster. So the Core of the Black Hole glows like hell.

For Peter on the Other hand. Time does not go that fast, which means the Black Hole still Glows, but so dimm and slow that he for the love of God cant see anything.

**Clean Up**

The Idea is pretty much that a Black Hole is just a Explosion in Slow Motion. Depending on your Time rate, it will look exactly like an Explosion.

So yeah, how wrong is that ? Thrilled to hear what you have to say and if that even remotly makes sense.

Thanks for reading and have a good day !

Sorry for misspellings, i am German

Comment: Explosion  needs energy  for the outgoing objects, " look like" is not the same as the title implies, that BH are explosions.

Comment: I's agree that the detailed arguments are wrong. But the primary observation, that singularities are an artefact of a partial theory hitting its boundary conditions, is shared by many physicists.

Comment: @safesphere i get what you mean, but how can you be certrain of that ? I do agree that i still have to learn a lot but that dosnt really change that a Volume 0 makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

> If you fell into a Black Hole, a few things happen. Firstly you never enter the Event Horizon, it is always in front of you. Second, the Universe will begin to speed up. To the point where you can see entire Galaxyies move.

Your understanding is incorrect on both these points.

From the point of view of a distant observer, they will never see you cross the event horizon. But from your point of view you cross the event horizon in finite time (as long as you survive spaghettification).

And you don't see the rest of the universe speeding up. Since your speed is increasing, from your point of view distant galaxies appear if anything to be slowing down.

Answer (score 0):

You have amazing timing (or you just bought a magazine).

Highly respected physicist Carlo Rovelli argues exactly this in his forthcoming book (due out on 5 November 2020), *There are Places in the World Where Rules are Less Important than Kindness*, Allen Lane, UK. The argument features in the current (31 October 2020) issue of *New Scientist* (which is how I know).

He suggests that the singularity is indeed BS, it is just an artefact of a theory hitting the buffers.

He suggests instead that the infalling matter will collapse to a super-dense "Planck star" and then rebound. Due to the extreme Relativistic conditions, from outside the rebound takes almost for ever but from inside it happens in "a few hundredths of a second".

but, being a good physicist, he ends on a word of caution; "Is this really the case? I don't know for sure. I think it might well be. The alternatives seem less plausible to me. But I could be wrong."

Comment: Thank the lord that i didnt oversee something that would render my thoughts invalid :D I had this thought for a bit even before i really went into Black Holes but i always thought it cant be right. Which maybe is not.

Ill read the Book as soons as i can, he is way smarter than i am so and if we both have the same idea it will be very interessting to see his pov. Because mine is a lot of "Why do you think that is ? -> Because"

Comment: Of course singularities in GR are a mathematical impasse **that is why theorist are looking  at quantization of gravity, and quantization of gravity is already use in the Big Bang  model, where there is no singularity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang